# Is there a way to add a separate node website under a node website's route?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have two Node.js websites (**website_a**, **website_b**) that use ExpressJS. I wanted to add **"website_b"** under a route of **"website_a"**.

For example, going to *http://www.website_a.com/website_b* will show the pages of **"website_b"**.

i.e. Requesting *http://www.website_a.com/website_b/* shall not redirect the request to **website_b** (*http://www.website_b.com/*) but instead fetch the request from **website_b** and respond from the **website_a** server.

The response on requesting *http://www.website_a.com/website_b/about* shall be the same as requesting *http://www.website_b.com/about*.

#### ⚠ The websites (**website_a**, **website_b**) are completely separate and shall stay separate.

Is there a way to use the `route.use()` to add route `/website_b` to **website_a** and let ExpressJS fetch the response from **website_b** and then respond the same from **website_a**'s server.

Comment: If you're not modifying the code of `website_b` or able to incorporate that code into `website_a`, then absolute links or ajax calls in `website_b` will be a problem as they will go directly to `website_b` and will return real `website_b` content and links that doesn't show as a sub-site of `a`.  So, you'd have to have a really smart proxy that rewrites both pages and code in `website_b`.  This would be really messy.  If `website_b` used nothing but relative links in both code and HTML, it would be more feasible.

Comment: are you rendering whole website using node and express or you are taking about rest api or backend server only ?

Comment: @SamarthSaxena I am rendering the whole website using node and express.

Comment: Do you want to send it to another websites on some routes. Another websites means different project. are you ok with that ?

Comment: The response on requesting **http://www.website_a.com/website_b/about** shall be the same as requesting **Http://www.website_b.com/about**. But don't redirect the  **http://www.website_a.com/website_b/about** to **Http://www.website_b.com/about**.

Instead, let **website_a** fetch the request from **website_b** and show under the route of **website_a**,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the thing you want ask it to proxy pass certain routes to another websites. I've do before with one npm module **http-proxy-middleware**

```
npm i http-proxy-middleware
```

Proxy /api requests to http://www.example.org

```
var express = require('express');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var app = express();

app.use(
  '/api',
  proxy({ target: 'http://www.example.org', changeOrigin: true })
);
app.listen(3000);

// http://localhost:3000/api/foo/bar -> http://www.example.org/api/foo/bar
```

So basically it will send request to another website under website one.

check out more about it - https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware

Hope it helps :)